# What are the difference between load view and executable view of a program?

Tags: c, executable, loadview

I was wondering what the differences between load view and executable view of a C program were.

I'm thinking executable view is the binary that is in the executable file. For load view I had a harder time thinking of what to come up with but thought it was possibly the .text and .data section of the program.

Comment: Source of these terms? When I google for "load view and execution view" I get **this** question as the first google match.

Comment: My embedded systems class homework asks this question: "What is the purpose of Zero Initialized (ZI) Data and .bss in ARM ELF format? What are the differences between load view and executable view of a program?" I couldn't find anything via the internet regarding those terms and we weren't given any class material on the terms either so I wasn't really sure if the terms were possibly made up :/

Comment: If they asked the question in homework, I'd guess that they defined the term in the lesson or textbook. What does it say?

Comment: The **2nd** Google search result is http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1362065902090.htm - which might just be relevant. Did **you** try googling first?

Comment: Yes I did but I must've had too broad of a search since it didn't yield me any results. Thanks!